# How to read save docx file contents in flask with flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, docx

I am trying to save the contents of a docx file in my flask application, using the python-docx libray. It seems to work outside of flask, but not sure where I am making a mistake. Help needed.

I have been able to save the simple .txt files using the read() function.

> Blockquote

```
@app.route('/add_document', methods = ['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def add_document():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title=request.form['title']
        file = request.files['file']
        allowed_extensions = ['txt','doc','docx']
        filename = file.filename
        file_extension = filename.split('.', 1)[1].lower()
        content=''
        if file:
            if file_extension in allowed_extensions:
                if file_extension == 'txt':
                    content = str(file.read())
                if file_extension == 'docx':
                    content = ''.join([para.text for para in Document(filename).paragraphs])
        else:
            content = request.form['text']
        summary = auto_summarize(content,20,topicing,2)
        topic = ', '.join([i for i in topicing(content,3)])
        document = Document(title=title, content=content, summary=summary,
                            topic=topic, owner=current_user)
        db.session.add(document)
        db.session.commit()
        # reader.close()
        flash('Document uploaded! Please visit MyDocs to see it!','success')
        return redirect(request.url)
    return render_template('add_document.html')
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

the for loop for reading docx file is just fetching the first line of the file.
below is just a demo code that might fit in right.

```
import docx
doc = docx.Document("abc.docx")
fullText = []
a=''
for para in doc.paragraphs:
  fullText.append(para.text)
a='\n'.join(fullText)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

for loop read paragraph by paragraph from your .docx file

```
from docx import Document

document = Document("file_path/file_name.docx")
for p in document.paragraphs:
    print(p.text)
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what the problem is and how the code helps.